# Numpy fast check for complete array equality, like Matlabs isequal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Matlab, the builtin `isequal` does a check if two arrays are equal.  If they are not equal, this might be very fast, as the implementation presumably stops checking as soon as there is a difference:

```
>> A = zeros(1e9, 1, 'single');    
>> B = A(:);                     
>> B(1) = 1;
>> tic; isequal(A, B); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000043 seconds.
```

Is there any equavalent in Python/numpy?  `all(A==B)` or `all(equal(A, B))` is far slower, because it compares *all* elements, even if the initial one differs:

```
In [13]: A = zeros(1e9, dtype='float32')                                                                                                                                                           

In [14]: B = A.copy()

In [15]: B[0] = 1

In [16]: %timeit all(A==B)
1 loops, best of 3: 612 ms per loop
```

Is there any numpy equivalent?  It should be very easy to implement in C, but slow to implement in Python because this is a case where we do *not* want to broadcast, so it would require an explicit loop.

**Edit:**

It appears `array_equal` does what I want.  However, it is *not* faster than `all(A==B)`, because it's not a built-in, but just a short Python function doing `A==B`.  So it does not meet my need for a *fast* check.

```
In [12]: %timeit array_equal(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 623 ms per loop
```

Comment: [`numpy.array_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)

Comment: Also *"all(equal(A, B)) is far slower, because it compares all elements, even if the initial one differs"* is not correct, `all` will early return if it encounters a `False`, just as `any` will early return after encountering `True`.

Comment: @Cyber But before `all` even starts, `equal(A, B)` has already compared *all* elements.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you are saying, my mistake.

Comment: @Cyber Edited question.  `array_equal` seemed great but is in fact just a short Python function that does `A==B` and therefore does not meet the `fast` requirement.

Comment: As a side remark, `array_equal` does more than check `A==B`: it checks the size of the array too. Notice that `all(np.zeros((3, 3)) == np.zeros((1, 3)))` is `True` but that `np.array_equal(np.zeros((3, 3)), np.zeros((1, 3)))` is `False`.

Comment: @ajcr True.  But checking that shapes are identical is fast no matter how large the array is, so not relevant as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: Maybe `numpy.allclose` is worth checking out.

Comment: @Akavall `allclose` is even slower, taking, according to `%timeit`, `8.46s` per loop.

Comment: `allclose` is slower by an order of magnitude.

Comment: `numpy.array_equiv` appears to be marginally faster, 17.9s vs 18.6s (using float64).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it should be noted that in the OP's example the arrays have identical elements because `B=A[:]` is just a view onto the array, so:

```
>>>  print A[0], B[0]
1.0, 1.0
```

But, although the test isn't a fit one, the basic complaint is true: Numpy does not have a short-circuiting equivalency check.

One can easily see from [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2056) that all of `allclose`, `array_equal`, and `array_equiv` are just variations upon `all(A==B)` to match their respective details, and are not notable faster.


An advantage of numpy though is that slices are just views, and are therefore very fast, so one could write their own short-circuiting comparison fairly easily (I'm not saying this is ideal, but it does work):

```
from numpy import *

A = zeros(1e8, dtype='float32')                                                                                                                                                         
B = A[:]
B[0] = 1
C = array(B)
C[0] = 2
D = array(A)
D[-1] = 2

def short_circuit_check(a, b, n):
    L = len(a)/n
    for i in range(n):
        j = i*L
        if not all(a[j:j+L]==b[j:j+L]):
                return False
    return True


In [26]: %timeit short_circuit_check(A, C, 100)   # 100x faster
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit all(A==C)
1 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit short_circuit_check(A, D, 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit all(A==D)
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop
```

Comment: Oops to the `[:]` correction.  Changed it to `B = A.copy()` in the question.  Must have gotten confused with lists.